# Function taking rvalue reference of a base class pointer is having pointers from derived classes copied

Tags: c++, pointers, rvalue-reference

Here's a quick minimal example of what I mean. I found it hard to succinctly phrase the question.

```
struct A {};
struct B : public A {};

void foo(A*&& ap)
{
    ap = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    B b;

    A* ap = &b;

    foo(std::move(ap));
    std::cout << (ap == nullptr ? "null" : "not null") << std::endl;

    B* bp = &b;

    foo(std::move(bp));
    std::cout << (bp == nullptr ? "null" : "not null") << std::endl;
}
```

I hoped this would print

```
null
null
```

but instead it prints

```
null
not null
```

A quick look at the x86 disassembly shows the unwanted copying occurring, only for the `B*` case:

```
lea         eax,[bp]  
push        eax  
call        std::move<B * &> (03E14BFh)  
add         esp,4  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]                     << Unwanted copy
mov         dword ptr [ebp-0ECh],ecx                << occurs here
lea         edx,[ebp-0ECh]  
push        edx  
call        foo (03E14B5h)  
add         esp,4
```

Is there any solution to this without changing the signature of `foo`? I'm very constrained by an external API as to what I can change about the hierarchy or the `foo` function.

Comment: What is the point of passing an *rvalue* reference to a pointer?

Comment: It's a class wrapping a resource handle from a C API (Java Native Interface). I want to null out the handle upon initialising the wrapper to prevent bugs with the raw handle being reused. The C API typedefs a pointer to empty struct as the handle type. Multiple handle types use the inheritance form I showed.

Comment: But that is not what **rvalue**-references are for. What you describe you would do with an *lvalue* reference.

Comment: @David, if I use a non-const lvalue reference then trying to call `foo(static_cast<A*>(bp));` won't compile.

Comment: You can create a second overload that takes the rvalue reference and forwards to the other. You are trying to walk a thin line there, the temporary cannot be bound by the non-const reference, but that is really the case where you don't need to reset the pointer, since no other code accesses it. But the premise is that you have a real *handle* and you want to reset it, not a temporary. The case where the lvalue reference won't work and the rvalue reference will is because a copy is being done and you are not affecting the original!! You **want** to bind the *lvalue* reference.

Comment: If you think about it, the case where the code won't do what you want is where the lvalue version will fail to compile making you aware of that fact. Using an rvalue reference *hides* this from you and you will have to find out why on earth the pointer that you set to null was not null, and then you end up asking in StackOverflow and... and... the rest is history. Now being serious: compiler errors are **not** a problem. If you encode in the type system your expectations the compiler will help you, that is what that the failure to compile in the lvalue reference is, the compiler helping you

Comment: @David You raise an awful lot of good points. I'll probably go the road of using overloads, but I will take your advice on board too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foo` takes a refence to an `A*`. You don't give it an `A*`, but instead a `B*`. This necessitates a conversion. A *temporary* `A*` is formed, bound to the rvalue reference, changed, and finally discarded. The original `B*` is never affected.

Comment: Thank you, I understand why `B*` isn't affected, but I'm wondering is there a way to affect it?

Comment: This can further be evidenced by changing `foo(A*&&)` to `foo(A*&)`: you'll get a compiler error because you can't bind a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference. @Eoin: short of using an intermediate `A*` pointer and cast it back to a `B*` afterwards (`A* pa = pb; foo(move(pa)); pb = static_cast<B*>(pa);`) I don't think you can do much about it.

Comment: @Eoin: Make another overload of `foo` that takes a `B*` by reference. And stop using rvalue references when you *clearly* want lvalue references. You should consider read-access after `move` undefined behaviour (it isn't, but you should think of it that way).

Comment: @Kerrek The function is taking ownership of the pointer. I just felt that move semantics expresses that intention clearer.

Comment: @Eoin: OK, then just add another overload for `B*&&`.

Comment: _just add another overload for B*&&_ or make template function